# JSON error retrieving data from database, after registration

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get some data from a databse using JSON, but debugging the app showed me that `Value null at ID_UTILIZ of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to int` . I have checked the database and the `ID_UTILIZ` column is set as `Int` . This activity is used for registering, and also storing the data for `SharedPreferences`, so I am using also a `User class`, but I have also set the `Id` at `int` there too. I cannot see what I am doing wrong

code:

```
class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("nume", Nume);
            params.put("email", Email);
            params.put("Parola", Parola_cont);
            params.put("prenume", Prenume);
            params.put("telefon", Telefon);
            params.put("departament", spinner);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_REGISTER, params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion

            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //getting the user from the response
                    JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                    //creating a new user object
                    User user = new User(
                            userJson.getString("Nume"),
                            userJson.getString("Prenume"),
                            userJson.getString("Adresa_mail"),
                            userJson.getString("Numar_telefon"),
                            userJson.getString("Parola"),
                            userJson.getInt("ID_UTILIZ"),
                            userJson.getString("Departament")
                    );

                    //storing the user in shared preferences
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //executing the async task
    RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
    ru.execute();
}
```

php:

```
case 'inregistrare':
            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('nume','email','Parola','prenume', 'telefon', 'departament'))){
                $prenume = $_POST["prenume"];
                $nume =$_POST["nume"];
                $email =$_POST["email"];
                $telefon =$_POST["telefon"];
                $parola =md5($_POST["Parola"]);
                $tip = 2;
                $departament=$_POST["departament"];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ FROM informatii_persoane WHERE Adresa_mail = ? OR Numar_telefon = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $telefon);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                    $response['error'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = 'Utilizator existent';
                    $stmt->close();
                }else{
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO informatii_persoane (Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon, Parola, Tip_utilizator, Departament) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sssssis", $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $parola, $tip, $departament);

                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID_UTILIZ, Nume, Prenume, Adresa_mail, Numar_telefon, Parola, Departament FROM informatii_persoane WHERE Adresa_mail = ?"); 
                        $stmt->bind_param("s",$Adresa_mail);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($id, $nume, $prenume, $email, $telefon, $parola, $departament);
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $user = array(
                            'Nume'=>$nume, 
                            'Prenume'=>$prenume,
                            'Adresa_mail'=>$email,
                            'Numar_telefon'=>$telefon,
                            'Parola'=>$parola,
                            'ID_UTILIZ'=>$id,
                            'Departament'=>$departament
                        );

                        $stmt->close();

                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Utilizator inregistrat cu success'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }
                }

            }else{
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'A aparut o eroare'; 
            }

        break;
```

The registering process it's working, I have all the data stored in database and I can log in later, but because of the error mentioned above, the code stops and:

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));
```

doesn't start the Home.class activity so my app stays on the same window. I have tried to search for other questions posted before, but none had a solution that worked. I think I am missing something, but I cannot see what. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't not convert `null` to `int`. So, you have to check first your specific value is not `null`.

Try like this

```
int id_utiliz = -1; // set default value

// check ID_UTILIZ is not null and then get value. 
if(!userJson.isNull("ID_UTILIZ")) {
    id_utiliz = userJson.getInt("ID_UTILIZ");
}
//creating a new user object
User user = new User(
    userJson.getString("Nume"),
    userJson.getString("Prenume"),
    userJson.getString("Adresa_mail"),
    userJson.getString("Numar_telefon"),
    userJson.getString("Parola"),
    id_utiliz, 
    userJson.getString("Departament")
);
```

And Use `finish()` below the `startActivity(...)` like the following.

```
SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));

finish(); // use this statement here.
```

Comment: It is working now, I added the code you've changed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that `ID_UTILIZ` has any value defined, it should not be null. OR you can simply assign a default value to `ID_UTILIZ` in your table.

Answer (score 0):

- **int** primitive type doesn't accept null values, you can use the **Integer** wrapper class which can have a value of null, usually when serializing JSON object from network call i use wrapper class not primitives.
- also use *responseJsonObject*.isNull(ID_UTILIZ) to check if object has no mapping for ID_UTILIZ or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.